# Can't move an input field in order to align it with other fields

Tags: html, css, input

[image]

The last input text field is a bit lower than the images on the left. These ones, at the same time, are higher than the rest of the elements.

I want to move the input type number at the same level as all the circle images and to move those to the same level as the X. However, when I try to add CSS properties, circles+input field are moved together. Can't figure out how to move only one element. Here is the code, removing unnecessary elements:

```css
table {     
  font-size: 7px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 45px;     
  text-align: center;    
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
th {     
  font-size: 9px;     
  font-weight: bold;     
  padding: 8px;     
  border-top: 4px solid #aabcfe;    
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; 
  color: #039; 
  height:5px;
}
td {    
  padding: 8px;     
  background: #e8edff;     
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #669;    
  border-top: 1px solid transparent; 
  white-space: nowrap ;
}
td:hover{
  background: #F1F1F2;    
}
tr:hover td {
  background-color: #ccd7ff;
}
.results {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(80%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  filter: grayscale(80%);
}
.results:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
.valueRes {
  font-style: italic; 
}
.extra {
  width: 300px;
}
#manual {
  float:right; /* without this, the input number field is below the circles and I need it next to them */
  height:8px;
  width:40px;
  font-size: 9px;  
  float:none;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table id="pendents">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="9"> data</th>
        <th id="valueRes" colspan="6" style="color: rgb(102, 102, 153);">Pendent</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="headers">
        <th>data</th>
        <th>Dia</th>
        <th>Hora</th>
        <th>data</th>
        <th class="extra">data</th>
        <th class="extra">data</th>
        <th class="extra">data</th>
        <th class="extra">data</th>
        <th>data</th>
        <th colspan="5">data</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="sube" id="0">
        <td>data</td>
        <td>24-06</td>
        <td>13:33:00</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>---</td>
        <td>---</td>
        <td>Mdata</td>
        <td>-5</td>
        <td><img src="./res/no.png" alt="HA" height="16" width="16"></td> 
        <td>
          <img src="./res/creurojo.png" class="results" alt="creurojo" height="16" width="16" id="creurojo0" onmouseover="Update(0, 0, 0);" onmouseout="Restore(0)" onclick="Update(5, 0,  {&quot;code&quot;:&quot;2016-06-24 13:33:48&quot;});">
          <img src="./res/hanegatiu.png" class="results" alt="hanegatiu" height="16" width="16" id="hanegatiu0" onmouseover="Update(1, 0, 0);" onmouseout="Restore(0)" onclick="Update(6, 0,  {&quot;code&quot;:&quot;2016-06-24 13:33:48&quot;});">
          <img src="./res/void.png" class="results" alt="void" height="16" width="16" id="void0" onmouseover="Update(2, 0, 0);" onmouseout="Restore(0)" onclick="Update(7, 0,  {&quot;code&quot;:&quot;2016-06-24 13:33:48&quot;});">
          <img src="./res/hapositiu.png" class="results" alt="hapositiu" height="16" width="16" id="hapositiu0" onmouseover="Update(3, 0, 0);" onmouseout="Restore(0)" onclick="Update(8, 0,  {&quot;code&quot;:&quot;2016-06-24 13:33:48&quot;});">
          <img src="./res/winverde.png" class="results" alt="winverde" height="16" width="16" id="winverde0" onmouseover="Update(4, 0, 0);" onmouseout="Restore(0)" onclick="Update(9, 0,  {&quot;code&quot;:&quot;2016-06-24 13:33:48&quot;});">
          <input type="number" id="manual" name="manual" step="any">
        </td>
      </tr>   
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Pretty sure this is somewhere but can't find it, too many related questions.

Comment: It is possible to do a vertical-align:top and margin-top: on #manual to get that input aligned as you wish.  You'll need to do some good cross-browser testing though :/

Comment: Share a jsfiddle if possible!

Comment: Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jeff mentioned in the comment, `vertical-align` will fix your problem but it might have cross-browser issue. Also you have un-even number of `<td>`. I have added one extra `<td>` for the input. I fixed your issue though correct your table layout.

```css
table {     
 font-size: 7px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 45px;     
 text-align: center;    
 border-collapse: collapse; 
}
th {     
 font-size: 9px;     
 font-weight: bold;     
 padding: 8px;     
 border-top: 4px solid #aabcfe;    
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; 
 color: #039; 
 height:5px;
}
td {    
 padding: 8px;     
 background: #e8edff;     
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #669;    
 border-top: 1px solid transparent; 
 white-space: nowrap ;
}
td:hover{
    background: #F1F1F2;    
}
tr:hover td {
    background-color: #ccd7ff;
}
.results
{
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(80%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 filter: grayscale(80%);
}
.results:hover
{
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 filter: grayscale(0%);
}
.valueRes
{
 font-style: italic; 
}
.extra
{
 width: 300px;
}
#manual
{
 float:right; /* without this, the input number field is below the circles and I need it next to them */
 height:8px;
 width:40px;
  font-size: 9px;  
 float:none;
 margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table id="pendents">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th colspan="9"> data
     </th><th id="valueRes" colspan="6" style="color: rgb(102, 102, 153);">Pendent</th></tr>
    <tr id="headers">
     <th>data</th>
     <th>Dia</th>
     <th>Hora</th>
     <th>data</th>
     <th class="extra">data</th>
     <th class="extra">data</th>
     <th class="extra">data</th>
     <th class="extra">data</th>
     <th>data</th>
     <th colspan="5">data</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="sube" id="0"><td>data</td><td>24-06</td><td>13:33:00</td><td>data</td><td>---</td><td>---</td><td>Mdata</td><td>-5</td><td><img src="./res/no.png" alt="HA" height="16" width="16"></td> <td>
         <img src="./res/creurojo.png" class="results" alt="creurojo" height="16" width="16" id="creurojo0" onmouseover="Update(0, 0, 0);" onmouseout="Restore(0)" onclick="Update(5, 0,  {&quot;code&quot;:&quot;2016-06-24 13:33:48&quot;});">
         <img src="./res/hanegatiu.png" class="results" alt="hanegatiu" height="16" width="16" id="hanegatiu0" onmouseover="Update(1, 0, 0);" onmouseout="Restore(0)" onclick="Update(6, 0,  {&quot;code&quot;:&quot;2016-06-24 13:33:48&quot;});">
         <img src="./res/void.png" class="results" alt="void" height="16" width="16" id="void0" onmouseover="Update(2, 0, 0);" onmouseout="Restore(0)" onclick="Update(7, 0,  {&quot;code&quot;:&quot;2016-06-24 13:33:48&quot;});">
         <img src="./res/hapositiu.png" class="results" alt="hapositiu" height="16" width="16" id="hapositiu0" onmouseover="Update(3, 0, 0);" onmouseout="Restore(0)" onclick="Update(8, 0,  {&quot;code&quot;:&quot;2016-06-24 13:33:48&quot;});">
         <img src="./res/winverde.png" class="results" alt="winverde" height="16" width="16" id="winverde0" onmouseover="Update(4, 0, 0);" onmouseout="Restore(0)" onclick="Update(9, 0,  {&quot;code&quot;:&quot;2016-06-24 13:33:48&quot;});">
         </td><td><input type="number" id="manual" name="manual" step="any">
        </td></tr>   </tbody>
  </table>
 
 

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Working :)

Comment: Welcome:) If you are satisfied with the solution, you can mark it as an answer.